# implode warning

Tags: php, mysql

I am moving to another server and now I am getting an implode warning "Invalid arguments passed", the script was working on the old server, does someone know what I am doing wrong???
My code is:

```
$query ="SELECT  keywords,keywords1,keywords2,keywords3 FROM Table "; 

$result = mysql_query($query); 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $arraykeywords[]=$row['keywords']."".$row['keywords1']."".$row['keywords2']."".$row['keywords3'];
}

$arraykeywords=implode("",$arraykeywords);
$arraykeywords=explode("/",$arraykeywords);

sort($arraykeywords);

$arraykeywords=array_unique($arraykeywords);

foreach($arraykeywords as $keywordsarr){}
```

Thanks in advance.
Hans

Comment: So that language interpreter "Implode" is giving you a warning, that's what you are saying? Or what language is that?

Comment: Seems to be php. Could you also let us know which warning was shown?

Answer (score 5):

I see implode works on $arraykeywords variable which is populated from DB. The most likely cause is that now your db query returns different results or no results at all. You can check that by dumping appropriate variables with var_dump();

One of the more common problems is forgetting to move database data :)

Comment: Shame on me. 
The problem was the DB, it did not return any results
Thank you very much.
Hans